# How can I get rid of the white space on my website?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm having an issue with my website, on all of the pages of my site in the main body there is a white gap. This is my index.php page:

```css
body {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  background: url(flame_bg.png) no-repeat left top;
}
#bg_container {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#bg {
  width: 100%;
}
#content {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  padding: 60px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#content2 {
  position: inherit;
  top: 10px;
  padding: 60px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>

  <p>&nbsp;</p>

  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <h1><span style="font-size:36px; color: #fd4000; font-family: 'Tahoma', Geneva, sans-serif;">Welcome, to Burning Chat</span></h1>

  <p><span style="font-size:24px; color=#fd4000; font-family: 'Tahoma', Geneva, sans-serif;">Whether you&#39;re browsing for a friend, or wanting to improve your business&#39; audience.</span>
  </p>

  <p><span style="font-size:24px; color=#fd4000; font-family: 'Tahoma', Geneva, sans-serif;">Burning Chat provides you with a sociable expierence to connect with your close ones wherever you are, and its free.</span>
  </p>
</div>


<div id="pageMiddle">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="pageBottom">&copy;2015 Burning Flame</div>
```

You can view the issue here: [www.burningchat.tk](http://burningchat.tk)

I also require the `<p>&nbsp;</p>` to lower the text on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after inspecting the dom it looks like your #pageMiddle has a height of 1000px.

in your stylesheet provide this:

```
#pageMiddle{
  height:0;
}
```

that should do the trick.

Comment: or just remove the <div id="pageMiddle"></div> altogether

Answer (score 0):

You give your `#content` and `#content2` a `padding:60px;`. This means that around these containers, you create 60px whitespace. Is that what you mean?

Apart from that, **your HTML is horribly in ruins**. There are no longer any tags `<font>`, let alone `<font-family>`, these have been deprecated a century ago. Use the corresponding CSS properties instead:

```
h1 {
    color: #fd4000;
    font-family: "Tahoma", Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Yeah recently found out about the new font technique.

Comment: You really need to learn at least the basics of css and html. Your code is the worst I've seen in a very, very, **very** long time.